# Validating input when mutating a dataclass

Tags: python, validation, python-dataclasses

In Python 3.7 there are these new "dataclass" containers that are basically like mutable namedtuples. Suppose I make a dataclass that is meant to represent a person. I can add input validation via the `__post_init__()` function like this:

```
@dataclass
class Person:
    name: str
    age: float

    def __post_init__(self):
        if type(self.name) is not str:
            raise TypeError("Field 'name' must be of type 'str'.")
        self.age = float(self.age)
        if self.age < 0:
            raise ValueError("Field 'age' cannot be negative.")
```

This will let good inputs through:

```
someone = Person(name="John Doe", age=30)
print(someone)

Person(name='John Doe', age=30.0)
```

While all of these bad inputs will throw an error:

```
someone = Person(name=["John Doe"], age=30)
someone = Person(name="John Doe", age="thirty")
someone = Person(name="John Doe", age=-30)
```

However, since dataclasses are mutable, I can do this:

```
someone = Person(name="John Doe", age=30)
someone.age = -30
print(someone)

Person(name='John Doe', age=-30)
```

Thus bypassing the input validation.

So, what is the best way to make sure that the fields of a dataclass aren't mutated to something bad, **after** initialization?

Comment: Use `@dataclass(frozen=True)` to make it "immutable"

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga that would defeat the purpose of using a dataclass in the first place. If I wanted an immutable data container I would just use a namedtuple. I intend to be able to update the fields sometime after having initialized the variable.

Comment: Well, namedtuples *are tuples*, a @dataclass is just a decorator that let's you skip writing a lot of boilerplate to create classes of a kind that are frequently encountered, it's not just "a mutable namedtuple". But then I suppose, you would have to hide your attributes behind a `property` or something, however, that would remove some of the niceness of the dataclass to begin with

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Dataclasses are a mechanism to provide a default initialization to accept the attributes as parameters, and a nice representation, plus some niceties like the `__post_init__` hook.

Fortunatelly, they do not mess with any other mechanism for attribute access in Python - and you can still have your dataclassess attributes being created as `property` descriptors, or a custom descriptor class if you want. In that way, any attribute access will go through your getter and setter functions automatically.

The only drawback for using the default `property` built-in is that you have to use it in the "old way", and not with the decorator syntax - that allows you to create annotations for your attributes.

So, "descriptors" are special objects assigned to class attributes in Python in a way that any access to that attribute will call the descriptors `__get__`, `__set__` or `__del__` methods. The `property` built-in is a convenince to build a descriptor passed 1 to 3 functions taht will be called from those methods.

So, with no custom descriptor-thing, you could do:

```
@dataclass
class MyClass:
   def setname(self, value):
       if not isinstance(value, str):
           raise TypeError(...)
       self.__dict__["name"] = value
   def getname(self):
       return self.__dict__.get("name")
   name: str = property(getname, setname)
   # optionally, you can delete the getter and setter from the class body:
   del setname, getname
```

By using this approach you will have to write each attribute's access as two methods/functions, but will no longer need to write your `__post_init__`: each attribute will validate itself.

Also note that this example took the little usual approach of storing the attributes normally in the instance's `__dict__`. In the examples around the web, the practice is to use normal attribute access, but prepending the name with a `_`. This will leave these attributes polluting a `dir` on your final instance, and the private attributes will be unguarded.

Another approach is to write your own descriptor class, and let it check the instance and other properties of the attributes you want to guard. This can be as sofisticated as you want, culminating with your own framework. So  for a descriptor class that will check for attribute type and accept a validator-list, you will need:

```
def positive_validator(name, value):
    if value <= 0:
        raise ValueError(f"values for {name!r}  have to be positive")

class MyAttr:
     def __init__(self, type, validators=()):
          self.type = type
          self.validators = validators

     def __set_name__(self, owner, name):
          self.name = name

     def __get__(self, instance, owner):
          if not instance: return self
          return instance.__dict__[self.name]

     def __delete__(self, instance):
          del instance.__dict__[self.name]

     def __set__(self, instance, value):
          if not isinstance(value, self.type):
                raise TypeError(f"{self.name!r} values must be of type {self.type!r}")
          for validator in self.validators:
               validator(self.name, value)
          instance.__dict__[self.name] = value

#And now

@dataclass
class Person:
    name: str = MyAttr(str)
    age: float = MyAttr((int, float), [positive_validator,])
```

That is it - creating your own descriptor class requires a bit more knowledge about Python, but the code given above should be good for use, even in production - you are welcome to use it.

Note that you could easily add a lot of other checks and transforms for each of your attributes - 
and the code in `__set_name__` itself could be changed to introspect the `__annotations__` in the `owner` class to automatically take note of the types - so that the type parameter would not be needed for the `MyAttr`  class itself. But as I said before: you can make this as sophisticated  as you want.

Comment: Note that using `property` makes it behave as a field with a default, i.e. it cannot be used before a field without a default ("TypeError: non-default argument 'second' follows default argument).  I've ended up using `__setattr__` on the wrapped dataclass to invalidate some cache if a field/attribute gets set.

Comment: Yes - dataclasses will take any field with a descriptor as having a  "default" - the only way to change that would be to assign the descriptors _after_ the `@dataclass` decorator has run - that would require both another decorator, and a way to annotate the descriptors themselves.

Comment: @jsbueno, I'm just starting to make sense of Python classes, but am I correct that in your first example, `"name"` should be quoted within  `self.__dict__.get(name)`?

Comment: Yes -it should have been quoted. I am fixing now.

Comment: Instead of explicitly creating your own descriptor class, it might be simpler, depending on what you're doing, to just use the built-in `property()` function to create one — similar to the `typed_property()` function shown in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60902129/355230) of mine.

Comment: I improved this answer to include default arguments in https://stackoverflow.com/a/71590530/1810940

Comment: Is using `type` as variable name okay to do here? Shouldn't that be avoided?

Answer (score 7):

A simple and flexible solution can be to override the`__setattr__` method:

```
@dataclass
class Person:
    name: str
    age: float

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        if name == 'age':
            assert value > 0, f"value of {name} can't be negative: {value}"
        self.__dict__[name] = value
```

Comment: While it works, this is not scalable. Better to use something a bit more meta / introspective.

Comment: @Rebs Why is it not scalable?

Comment: Doing this also means you can't make your dataclass immutable (`frozen`), as in `@dataclass(frozen=True)`. To combat this, I just check if the field has already been set yet.

Comment: Besides `frozen`, this does not work with `@dataclass(slots=True)` because slotted classes cannot have `__setattr__`.

Comment: @creyesk it's stringly typed

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps lock down the attribute using [getters and setters](https://www.python-course.eu/python3_properties.php) instead of mutating the attribute directly. If you then extract your validation logic into a separate method, you can validate the same way from both your setter and the `__post_init__` function.

Answer (score 1):

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54489602/1810940) provided by [@jsbueno](https://stackoverflow.com/users/108205/jsbueno) is great, but it doesn't allow for default arguments. I expanded it to allow defaults:

```
def positive_validator(name, value):
    if value <= 0:
        raise ValueError(f"values for {name!r}  have to be positive")

class MyAttr:
    def __init__(self, typ, validators=(), default=None):
        if not isinstance(typ, type):
            if isinstance(typ, tuple) and all([isinstance(t,type) for t in typ]):
                pass
            else:
                raise TypeError(f"'typ' must be a {type(type)!r} or {type(tuple())!r}` of {type(type)!r}")
        else:
            typ=(typ,)
        self.type = typ
        self.name = f"MyAttr_{self.type!r}"
        self.validators = validators
        self.default=default
        if self.default is not None or type(None) in typ:
            self.__validate__(self.default)
        
    def __set_name__(self, owner, name):
        self.name = name
    
    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        if not instance: return self
        return instance.__dict__[self.name]

    def __delete__(self, instance):
        del instance.__dict__[self.name]
        
    def __validate__(self, value):
        for validator in self.validators:
            validator(self.name, value)
            
    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        if value == self:
            value = self.default
        if not isinstance(value, self.type):
            raise TypeError(f"{self.name!r} values must be of type {self.type!r}")

        instance.__dict__[self.name] = value
        


#And now

@dataclass
class Person:
    name: str = MyAttr(str,[]) # required attribute, must be a str, cannot be none
    age: float = MyAttr((int, float), [positive_validator,],2) # optional attribute, must be an int >0, defaults to 2
    posessions: Union[list, type(None)] = MyAttr((list, type(None)),[]) # optional attribute in which None is default
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my improve for descriptors, you can define wour own functions

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
import re
from enum import Enum


class Descriptor:
    def __init__(self, type, validators=(), **kwargs):
        self.type = type
        self.default = kwargs.get("default")
        self.validators = validators
        self.kwargs = kwargs

    def __set_name__(self, owner, name):
        self.name = name

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        if not instance:
            return self
        # return instance.__dict__[self.name]
        return instance.__dict__.get(self.name, self.default)

    def __delete__(self, instance):
        del instance.__dict__[self.name]

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        if isinstance(value, Descriptor):
            value = self.default
        else:
            if not isinstance(value, self.type):
                raise TypeError(
                    f"{self.name!r} VALUES MUST BE TYPE {self.type!r} NOT {type(value)}!"
                )
            switch = {
                "POSITIVE": self.val_positive,
                "BETWEEN": self.val_between_values,
                "MAXMINZISE": self.val_between_sizes,
                "SIZE": self.val_size,
                "EMAIL": self.val_email,
                "NUMBER": self.val_number,
                "ONEOF": self.val_one_of,
            }
            for validator in self.validators:
                if validator in switch:
                    switch[validator](value)
        instance.__dict__[self.name] = value

    def val_positive(self, value: int | float):
        if value <= 0:
            raise ValueError(f"VALUE IS NOT VALID FOR {self.name!r} MUST BE POSITIVE")

    def val_between_values(self, value: int | float):
        maxval = self.kwargs.get("maxval")
        if maxval is not None:
            if not isinstance(maxval, int) or isinstance(maxval, float):
                raise TypeError(
                    f"MAX VALUE MUST BE TYPE INTEGER OR FLOAT NOT {type(value)}!"
                )
            if value > maxval:
                raise ValueError(
                    f"VALUE IS NOT VALID FOR {self.name!r} MUST BE GREATER THAN {maxval}"
                )
        minval = self.kwargs.get("minval")
        if minval is not None:
            if not isinstance(minval, int) or isinstance(maxval, float):
                raise TypeError(
                    f"MIN VALUE MUST BE TYPE INTEGER OR FLOAT NOT {type(value)}!"
                )
            if value < minval:
                raise ValueError(
                    f"VALUE IS NOT VALID FOR {self.name!r} MUST BE LESS THAN {minval}"
                )

    def val_between_sizes(self, value: int):
        maxsize = self.kwargs.get("maxsize")
        if maxsize is not None:
            if not isinstance(maxsize, int):
                raise TypeError(f"MAX VALUE MUST BE TYPE INTEGER NOT {type(value)}!")
            if len(value) > maxsize:
                raise ValueError(
                    f"VALUE IS NOT VALID FOR {self.name!r} MUST BE GREATER THAN {maxsize}"
                )
        minsize = self.kwargs.get("minsize")
        if minsize is not None:
            if not isinstance(minsize, int):
                raise TypeError(f"MIN VALUE MUST BE TYPE INTEGER NOT {type(value)}!")
            if len(value) < minsize:
                raise ValueError(
                    f"VALUE IS NOT VALID FOR {self.name!r} MUST BE LESS THAN {minsize}"
                )

    def val_size(self, value: str):
        length = self.kwargs.get("size")
        if length is None:
            raise ValueError("LEN NOT DEFINED")
        if len(value) > length:
            raise ValueError(
                f"VALUE IS NOT VALID FOR {self.name!r} THE LIMIT OF CHACRTERS IS {length}"
            )

    def val_email(self, value: str):
        regex = r"\b[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z|a-z]{2,}\b"
        if not re.fullmatch(regex, value):
            raise ValueError("MAIL NOT VALID")

    def val_number(self, value: str):
        regex = "[0-9]+"
        if not re.match(regex, value):
            raise ValueError("STRING NUMBER NOT VALID")

    def val_one_of(self, value: str):
        posible_values = self.kwargs.get("posible_values")
        if posible_values is None:
            raise ValueError("POSIBLE VALUES NOT DEFINED")
        if not issubclass(posible_values, Enum):
            raise TypeError(f"POSIBLE VALUES MUST BE TYPE ENUM NOT {type(value)}!")
        values = [e.value for e in posible_values]
        if value not in values:
            raise ValueError(
                f"VALUE IS NOT VALID FOR {self.name!r} IS NOT PRESENT IN ARRAY {posible_values}"
            )
@dataclass
class Person():
   personid: str = Descriptor((str), ["SIZE"], size=8)
```