# Repeating decorators for instance variables

Tags: python, class, variables, instance, decorator

I am writing a class where I need to check whether the instance variables are of a certain type.

I noticed that there is a lot of repeating code.
Is there a better way to do similar checks on the instance variables?
Or is this the right way to do it?

```
class Variable():

    __type = 'Variable'

    def __init__(self, id = None, updateable = True, name = 'Variable', value=None):
        if id is not None:
            self.id = id
        if value is not None:
            self.value = value
        self.updateable = updateable
        self.name = name

    @property
    def id(self):
        return self.__id

    @id.setter
    def id(self, id=None):
        if isinstance(id, int):
            self.__id = id
        else:
            raise Exception('"id" must be an integer ')

    @property
    def updateable(self):
        return self.__updateable

    @updateable.setter
    def updateable(self, updateable=None):
        if isinstance(updateable, bool):
            self.__updateable = updateable
        else:
            raise Exception('"updateatable" must be a bool')

    @property
    def name(self):
        return self.__name

    @name.setter
    def name(self, name=None):
        if isinstance(name, str):
            self.__name = name
        else:
            raise Exception('"name" must be a string')

    @property
    def value(self):
        return self.__value

    @value.setter
    def value(self, value=None):
        if isinstance(value, np.ndarray):
            self.__value = value
        else:
            raise Exception('"value" not an instance of np.ndarray')
```

Comment: Have you seen the answers here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9305751/force-ensure-python-class-attributes-to-be-of-specific-type The decorator `auto_attr_check` there seems interesting and also the library [pydantic](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/) might help you. Does that fit you?

Comment: If you're using python > 3.7, you can look into [dataclasses](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The book [*Python Cookbook, 3rd Edition*](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920027072.do)  by Jones & Beazley contains recipe **9.21 Avoiding Repetitive Property Methods** which does almost exactly what you need — I highly recommend getting a copy of the book (or e-book) to anyone interested becoming a proficient Python programmer more quickly as it contains many gems like this. (Disclaimer: I have no affiliation with the publisher or authors.)

Just about everything in Python is a first-class object, so it's possible to make a function that simply defines the property and returns it. Doing things this way will allow you to follow the [DRY Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) (and write less boring redundant code).

```
def typed_property(name, expected_type):
    storage_name = '__' + name

    @property
    def prop(self):
        return getattr(self, storage_name)

    @prop.setter
    def prop(self, value):
        if not isinstance(value, expected_type):
            type_name = expected_type.__name__
            raise TypeError('"{}" must be a {}'.format(name, type_name))
        setattr(self, storage_name, value)

    return prop


class Variable():
    __type = 'Variable'

    id = typed_property('id', int)
    updateable = typed_property('updateable', bool)
    name = typed_property('name', str)
    value = typed_property('value', np.ndarray)

    def __init__(self, id=None, updateable=True, name='Variable', value=None):
        if id is not None:
            self.id = id
        if value is not None:
            self.value = value
        self.updateable = updateable
        self.name = name
```

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for. Thank you for your help.

Comment: The usage of "__" in this form won't trigger the name mangling mechanism.  Although it will effectively "hide"  the storage attribute name, it will actually make impossible for code in the class to get to it - one have to keep that in mind.

Comment: @jsbueno: True…I just left it the way the OP had it.