# How to limit values in dataclass attribute?

Tags: python, python-dataclasses

I have the following dataclass `Gear` that I want to limit the maximum value for gear_level from 0 to 5.  But as you can see when I increment gear_level, it goes higher than 5, which is not what I want. I tried method as well as **postinit**. How do I fix this problem?

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Gear:
    gear_level: int = 0
    direction: str = None
    # more codes ...

    def __postinit__(self):
        if self.gear_level <= 0:
            self.gear_level = 0
        elif 5 > self.gear_level > 0:
            self.gear_level = self.gear_level
        else:
            self.gear_level = 5

    def set_gear_level(self, level):
        if level <= 0:
            self.gear_level = 0
        elif 5 > level > 0:
            self.gear_level = level
        else:
            self.gear_level = 5


g = Gear()

g.set_gear_level(6)

print(g)

g.gear_level += 1

print(g)

g.set_gear_level(-1)

print(g)

g.gear_level -= 1
print(g)
```

Ideally, I prefer to use the g.gear_level += 1 notation, because I want to increment gear_level.  It should not jump from gear level 1 to 5.  Also, when it decrement, it should stop at 0.  It should take both an assignment of 0 and be allowed to decrement to 0. Can this be done?

```
Gear(gear_level=5, direction=None)
Gear(gear_level=6, direction=None)
Gear(gear_level=0, direction=None)
Gear(gear_level=-1, direction=None)
```

Comment: Write a *regular* class and use a descriptor (that limits the value) as the attribute.

Comment: Keep in mind that the descriptor will have to implement things like `__iadd__` for `g.gear_level += 1` to work. You can't simply make an `int`-valued attribute behave like something else.

Comment: Does [Validating input when mutating a dataclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54488765/validating-input-when-mutating-a-dataclass) answer your question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case I would simply use a property:

```
@dataclass
class Gear:
    gear_level: int

    # Rest of the class excluded for simplicity

    @property
    def gear_level(self) -> int:
        return self._gear_level

    @gear_level.setter
    def gear_level(self, value: int) -> None:
        self._gear_level = min(max(value, 0), 5)
```

This way you don't need to write a `__post_init__` or have to remember to call specific methods: assignment to `gear_level` will be kept `0 <= gear_level <= 5`, even with `+=`.

Comment: I think this is the solution the OP is looking for: this isn't a Q about validating input when creating a class object, but simply having a limit imposed when setting values - which is exactly the use case property/getter/setters best fit IMO.

Comment: Right, but imagine if you're declaring more than one attribute with some set constraints. You could easily go with property route, but then you'll need to write **more** (basically duplicate) lines to achieve the same result. As well, I'd argue that the use case of properties is more for additional processing that needs to be done, like for example gathering data from other class attributes and other similar logic. I'd argue that the use case of properties isn't necessarily well suited for validation such as this (though it could easily work out as well in the end, of course).

Comment: I agree that in more complex cases, writing a custom descriptor could be useful (although in that case I would actually recommend looking into libraries like Pydantic). For the OP, I think this would be a case of YAGNI.

Comment: With instance, g=Gear(0),  g.gear_level -= 1 works perfectly. How do I modify it so that it will work with g=Gear(), as well?

Comment: @rv.kvetch You're right - in the 'extended' use case your fit is better.  ...separate issue, I think this kind of "validate the data" use case is very very common, and in general perhaps is a case for moving pydantic into the standard libraries to extend dataclasses.  What's your thoughts on that?

Comment: @vt2424253 If you give `gear_level` a default value, that should work.

Comment: @Richard hmm, to be honest I've personally never gotten on the bandwagon with the whole "validate the data" thing. I understand that's kind of in pydantic's wheelhouse, but at least I haven't worked on a project yet that was big on validating client input. That said, I do see its uses certainly, and see how it could be beneficial to others. I wouldn't be against the idea of adding pydantic to the stdlib, though I imagine there might be concerns due to the codebase being overall larger than dataclasses at least.

Comment: @rv.kvetch I think validation is one of those things that in some use cases is critical, otherwise not used much at all.  I have seen a) validation plus b) schema generation a lot when I have been writing API code, (either as API generator or consumer).   In those use cases in my experience you're a) passing json back and forth, b) wanting to check input/output matches published schemas.  Here is where I see there is a key need for pydantic over plain dataclasses.

Answer (score 3):

The suggested link in the comments provides an *elegant* solution for tackling this issue, e.g. using a custom [descriptor class](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#id1)  which should work with minimal changes needed on your end.

For example, here's how I'd define a `BoundsValidator` descriptor class to check that a class attribute is within an expected lower and upper bounds (note that either bounds are optional in this case):

```py
from typing import Optional

try:
    from typing import get_args
except ImportError:  # Python 3.7
    from typing_extensions import get_args


class BoundsValidator:
    """Descriptor to validate an attribute x remains within a specified bounds.

    That is, checks the constraint `low <= x <= high` is satisfied. Note that
    both low and high are optional. If none are provided, no bounds will be
    applied.
    """
    __slots__ = ('name',
                 'type',
                 'validator')

    def __init__(self, min_val: Optional[int] = None,
                 max_val: Optional[int] = float('inf')):

        if max_val is None:     # only minimum
            def validator(name, val):
                if val < min_val:
                    raise ValueError(f"values for {name!r}  have to be > {min_val}; got {val!r}")

        elif min_val is None:   # only maximum
            def validator(name, val):
                if val > max_val:
                    raise ValueError(f"values for {name!r}  have to be < {max_val}; got {val!r}")

        else:                   # both upper and lower bounds are given
            def validator(name, val):
                if not min_val <= val <= max_val:
                    raise ValueError(f"values for {name!r}  have to be within the range "
                                     f"[{min_val}, {max_val}]; got {val!r}")

        self.validator = validator

    def __set_name__(self, owner, name):
        # save the attribute name on an initial run
        self.name = name

        # set the valid types based on the annotation for the attribute
        #   for example, `int` or `Union[int, float]`
        tp = owner.__annotations__[name]
        self.type = get_args(tp) or tp

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        if not instance:
            return self
        return instance.__dict__[self.name]

    def __delete__(self, instance):
        del instance.__dict__[self.name]

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        # can be removed if you don't need the type validation
        if not isinstance(value, self.type):
            raise TypeError(f"{self.name!r} values must be of type {self.type!r}")

        # validate that the value is within expected bounds
        self.validator(self.name, value)

        # finally, set the value on the instance
        instance.__dict__[self.name] = value
```

Finally, here's the sample code I came up with to test that it's working as we'd expect:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Union


@dataclass
class Person:
    age: int = BoundsValidator(1)   # let's assume a person must at least be 1 years
    num: Union[int, float] = BoundsValidator(-1, 1)
    gear_level: int = BoundsValidator(0, 5)


def main():
    p = Person(10, 0.7, 5)
    print(p)

    # should raise a ValueError now
    try:
        p.gear_level += 1
    except ValueError as e:
        print(e)

    # and likewise here, for the lower bound
    try:
        p.gear_level -= 7
    except ValueError as e:
        print(e)

    # all these should now raise an error

    try:
        _ = Person(0, 0, 2)
    except ValueError as e:
        print(e)

    try:
        _ = Person(120, -3.1, 2)
    except ValueError as e:
        print(e)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This provides the output below when we run the code:

```
Person(age=10, num=0.7, gear_level=5)
values for 'gear_level'  have to be within the range [0, 5]; got 6
values for 'gear_level'  have to be within the range [0, 5]; got -2
values for 'age'  have to be within the range [1, inf]; got 0
values for 'num'  have to be within the range [-1, 1]; got -3.1
```

Answer (score 2):

There is also an excellent library called [param](https://param.holoviz.org/user_guide/Parameter_Types.html#strings) that enables you to achieve this rather easily. In your case it would look something like this:

```
import param

@dataclass
class Gear:
    gear_level: int = param.Integer(1, bounds=(0,5))
    direction: str = None


g = Gear()
print(g)
g.gear_level = 42 # This throws an exception
```

It has many other neat features for designing robust interfaces.