# How can I limit the value of the data class while still complying with Pylance?

Tags: python-3.x

I was able to limit the value of the dataclass property with the help of [THIS POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70686205/how-to-limit-values-in-dataclass-attribute).

```
@dataclass
class Permissions():
    allow: int
    deny: int

    @property
    def deny(self):
        return self.__deny
    
    @deny.setter
    def deny(self, value: int):
        if not 0 <= value <= 5:
            raise Exception()
        self.__deny = value
```

The code works without error, but Pylance gives me the following message

`Declaration "deny" is obscured by a declaration of the same name`

Is there any way to put a getter setter on the dataclass value in compliance with Pylance?

Comment: `deny` can't be both an `int` attribute and a property descriptor. You presumably want to delete the incorrect line `deny: int`, and perhaps add `-> int` to the getter definition. Your use of `__deny` is also very questionable. What's your inheritance use case that you need name mangling?

Comment: Also, do note that a class having invariants is at odds with being a dataclass.